# Remove autofocus attribute from field in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a sign up form, I have a few custom fields before the username. What's happening is that by default the focus is on the username field and I can't remove the autofocus attribute from this field.

I know I can work around using JavaScript but I'm trying to do this in the right way on Django.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from project.userprofile.models import UserProfile

class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = 'off'
```

Did I miss something?

***UPDATE***

The solution is:

```
self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.pop("autofocus", None)
```

Thanks @mariodev!

Comment: What do you mean, disable it? autofocus isn't something that's enabled by default, you have to actually add the attribute.

Comment: I think the right term is remove instead of disable. It's default for me here in my case the username field but I have a few fields before this one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman to clarify, you can pass attributes to the fields, autocomplete, autofocus, etc. In my case I just want to remove the autofocus from one field and I can't make it work.

Comment: @henriquea You should be able to do: `self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.pop("autofocus", None)`

Comment: @mariodev of course, did work! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 7):

(From a comment by @mariodev)

You should be able to do:

```python
self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.pop("autofocus", None)
```

to remove the item from the `attrs` collection [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the specified item exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *django_widget_tweaks*, you can remove the *autofocus* by using
"remove_attr".

Eg:

```
{{ form.username|remove_attr:"autofocus" }}
```